# Which gods are more powerful than Yama?

Tags: yama

Yama is considered as the one of the most powerful person in the universe. No can win with him.

Which people are more powerful than him ?

Shiva obviously should be more powerful than him . I think Vishnu too should be more powerful than him.

Is Brahma also more powerful than Yama ?

Which gods are more powerful than him ?

Comment: Yes Lord brahma being like the pitamah of the devas is surely powerful than any deva. He was the first to be created. So in any case, Brahma deva is powerful than yama deva......Apart from this, IMO Lord Indra CAN BE more powerful than Yama deva because he is the king of the devas.